# Enabling Azure AD Auth for Swagger UI hosted in Service Fabric

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-service-fabric, swagger-ui

We enabled Swagger for Web API application which is hosted on Azure Service Fabric. We want to enable security on Swagger UI. So I followed below url which enables security –
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pratushb/2016/04/28/enable-swagger-to-authenticate-against-azure-ad/
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/671 (response from Oleksandr-Tokmakov)

I could see the “Available authorizations” popup and I could see AAD authentication done successfully on another tab on click of Authorize button. But once authentication completed, I see the token not returns back to swagger ui and the authentication tab not closes.

Below is the code I used. (I created two AAD, one for Web Services hosted on Service Fabric and another for Swagger UI)

```
 config.EnableSwagger(
   c =>
    {
        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Title of Service");
        c.OAuth2("oauth2")
            .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
            .Flow("implicit")
            .AuthorizationUrl("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenentId-guid/oauth2/authorize")
            .Scopes(scopes =>
            {
                scopes.Add("user_impersonation", "Access Services Local Swagger Secure");
            });
        c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();
    }
).EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
{
    c.EnableOAuth2Support(
            clientId: "Swagger AAD application Client Id",
            clientSecret: "Swagger AAD application Key",
            realm: "https://localhost:444/swagger/ui/o2c-html",
            appName: "https://serviceslocal/swagger/", // Free text, no reference to AAD
            scopeSeperator: "",
            additionalQueryStringParams: new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "resource", "Web API AAD application Client Id" } }
        );
}
);


public class AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            // Correspond each "Authorize" role to an oauth2 scope
            var scopes = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline()
                .Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
                .SelectMany(attr => attr.Roles.Split(','))
                .Distinct();
            if (scopes.Any())
            {
                if (operation.security == null)
                    operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
                var oAuthRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                { "oauth2", scopes }
            };
                operation.security.Add(oAuthRequirements);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Auth0, but here's what I got for OAuth2 that works for me.

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
{
    Type = "oauth2",
    Flow = "implicit",
    AuthorizationUrl = Path.Combine(auth0Settings["Authority"].Value, "authorize")
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
    c.InjectOnCompleteJavaScript("/swagger-ui.js");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Easy Streak API");
    c.ConfigureOAuth2(auth0Settings["ClientId"].Value, auth0Settings["ClientSecret"].Value, auth0Settings["Authority"].Value, "EasyStreak API");
});
```